# selecting from joined tables - incomplete table

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables: 'cat_page' and 'pages'. The 'cat_page' table is an association of categories and the pages that are contained within. The 'pages' table contains data concerning the pages. I am allowing users to vote on the page, in which the total_votes is a column within 'pages'.

I am trying to create a query in which I can select all pages within a category that does not yet have any votes. The part I cannot get past is there are many pages in 'cat_page' that do no have an associated row in 'pages'. If I put in:

```
AND pages.total_votes > 0
```

into the commented part below, I'll select only the pages in which pages.total_votes = 0, but not any of the cat_page.page that have no associated page in 'pages'.

Any help is appreciated.

```
$data = array($lastcat);
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT cat_page.page FROM cat_page
LEFT JOIN pages ON cat_page.page = pages.page
WHERE cat_page.cat_id = ?
/// unsure what to do here
");
```

Comment: If you are putting `cat_id` in where clause then add `AND pages.total_votes = 0`, and if you want to get it for all `cat_id`s then use `WHERE pages.total_votes = 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you perform a left outer join the column that does not exist will come up NULL

```
AND (pages.toatl_votes IS NULL OR pages.total_votes = 0)
```

should solve your problem.  Greater than NULL is false.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue that you're having is that you're using a LEFT JOIN on cat_page, but you should probably be opting for a right join instead.

```
SELECT cat_page.page FROM cat_page
RIGHT JOIN pages ON cat_page.page = pages.page
WHERE cat_page.cat_id = ? and page.total_votes = 0
```

Hope that helps.